# awk match multiple regular expression strings and digits from a line

Tags: linux, awk, gnu

I am trying to match multiple items in each line in a httpd log file. The lines look like this:

```
192.168.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2016:16:35:42 +0100] "-"  "100" "GET /breacher/gibborum.do?firstnumber=1238100121135&simple=1238100121135&protocol=http&_super=telco1 HTTP/1.1" 200 161 "-" "NING/1.0"
192.168.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2016:16:35:44 +0100] "-"  "00" "GET /breacher/gibborum.do?firstnumber=1237037630256&simple=1237037630256&protocol=http&_super=telco1 HTTP/1.1" 200 136 "-" "NING/1.0"
192.168.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2016:16:35:44 +0100] "-"  "00" "GET /breacher/gibborum.do?firstnumber=1238064400578&simple=1238064400578&protocol=http&_super=telco1 HTTP/1.1" 200 136 "-" "NING/1.0"
```

I am trying to extract the numbers, the timestamp and the value of the _super variable. So far I can extract the numbers and the timestamp with this:

```
 awk '{match ($0, /123([0-9]+)/, arr); print $4, arr[0]}'
```

Please how do I extract the value at the end of the _super= variable as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your script like this: (add the `gsub` and the `$9`):

```
awk '{match ($0, /123([0-9]+)/, arr); gsub(/.*_super=/, "",$9); print $4, arr[0], $9}'
```